# **Edited** NextJS - Use of OutsideClickHandler on a Burger/Dropdown menu - getting both the OutsideClickHandler AND the Links working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a project in NextJS, where I'm making the NavBar component.
In wide screen it's got the links along the top, and in mobile there's a burger menu which opens a dropdown
Up to this point it all works great, links work.
Then I thought it'd be nice to add an OutsideClickHandler for when it's in mobile mode - i wired in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-outside-click-handler
but with this addition, the links for my dropdown no longer work - effectively the whole screen (aside from my burger) is being 'listened to' at triggering the OutsideClick.

I'm extremely new to all this. I figure it's because it's just listening to the burger icon. But I have no idea where to start to remedy this, and would super appreciate some input!  Half a thought being to apply the OutsideClick handler to the SideMenu component somehow, but I'm puzzled because it's logic otherwise is in NavBar.

Thanks so much.

My apologies I can't link to github as I'm on a branch and my mentor is busy on a tech interview and I don't want to pull request it yet!

**NavBar.js** - **without** OutsideClickHandler - links on Side Menu work fine

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

import styles from "../NavBar/NavBar.module.css";

import ButtonBase from "../button/buttonPrimary";
import SideMenu from "../SideMenu/SideMenu";

import MenuItems from "../../../data/MenuItems/MenuItems";
const NavBar = () => {
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    if (menuIsOpen === false) {
      setMenuIsOpen(true);
    } else {
      setMenuIsOpen(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <nav className={styles.navBarBox}>
      <div className={styles.menuIcon}>
        <i className={"fas fa-bars fa-2x"} onClick={toggleMenu}></i>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.mobileSideMenu}>
        {menuIsOpen ? <SideMenu /> : <div></div>}
      </div>

      <ul className={styles.navMenu}>
        {MenuItems.map((item) => (
          <li className={styles.navItem} key={item.id}>
            <Link href={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <Link href="/contact-me">
        <a className={styles.contactMeWeb}>
          <ButtonBase label="Contact Me" isPrimary={false}></ButtonBase>
        </a>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/contact-me">
        <a className={styles.contactMeMobile}>
          <i className={"fa-solid fa-message fa-2x"}> </i>
        </a>
      </Link>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

**NavBar.js** - **with** OutsideClickHandler - OutsideClickHandler works, but links in side menu only act as an outside click

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import OutsideClickHandler from "react-outside-click-handler";

import styles from "../NavBar/NavBar.module.css";

import ButtonBase from "../button/buttonPrimary";
import SideMenu from "../SideMenu/SideMenu";

import MenuItems from "../../../data/MenuItems/MenuItems";

const NavBar = () => {
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <nav className={styles.navBarBox}>
      <OutsideClickHandler
        onOutsideClick={() => {
          setMenuIsOpen(false);
        }}
      >
{/* BURGER ICON */}
        <a
          className={styles.menuIcon}
          onClick={() => setMenuIsOpen(!menuIsOpen)}
        >
          <i className={"fas fa-bars fa-2x"}></i>
        </a>
      </OutsideClickHandler>

{/* SIDE MENU */}
      {menuIsOpen && (
        <div className={styles.mobileSideMenu}>
          <SideMenu />
        </div>
      )}

      <ul className={styles.navMenu}>
        {MenuItems.map((item) => (
          <li className={styles.navItem} key={item.id}>
            <Link href={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <Link href="/contact-me">
        <a className={styles.contactMeWeb}>
          <ButtonBase label="Contact Me" isPrimary={false}></ButtonBase>
        </a>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/contact-me">
        <a className={styles.contactMeMobile}>
          <i className="fa-regular fa-envelope fa-2x"></i>
        </a>
      </Link>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

**SideMenu.js**

```
import MenuItems from "../../../data/MenuItems/MenuItems";


import styles from "../SideMenu/SideMenu.module.css";

const SideMenu = () => {
 


  return (
    <div className={styles.mobileMenuBox}>

      <ul className={styles.mobileMenu}>
      {MenuItems.map((item) => (
          <li className={styles.mobileItem} key={item.id}>
            <Link href={item.path}><div>{item.title}</div></Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

    </div>
  );
};

export default SideMenu;
```

Comment: where did you use OutsideClickHandler?

Comment: Awe dang, my apologies..... I added the version without the outside click handler.... Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!**
I just dragged the:

```
      {menuIsOpen && (
        <div className={styles.mobileSideMenu}>
          <SideMenu />
        </div>
      )}
```

between the

```
<OutsideClickHandler></OutsideClickHandler>
```

tags